# Floating-point types as template parameter in C++20

Tags: c++, templates, floating-point, c++20

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) C++20 now supports floating-point parameters in templates.
I am, however, unable to find any compiler support information on that site as well as on others.
Current gcc trunk just does it, the others are negative.

I would just like to know if this is a very low-priortity feature and/or when to expect it to become commonly supported.

The only related thing I can find is:
P0732R2 Class types in non-type template parameters. Kudos if anyone could briefly explain that instead.

Comment: From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) *Inconsistencies with non-type template parameters* looks like GCC9 and MSVC 19.26

Comment: It seems that _only_ gcc trunk supports this, and even the most recent gcc 10.2 doesn't. Given that the rationale for not supporting floating point in the past was due to the way that floating point representations work (where `0.0 != -0.0`, thus causing different instantiations per value), it could just be that this is a tough feature to implement

Comment: I'm going to say that even on gcc this feature is still incubating, judging by the segfault that gets created by having [two simultaneous instantiations](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/rqx4x7) of `Foo<0.0f>` and `Foo<-0.0f>`

Comment: @Human-Compiler: That, subnormal numbers, NaNs. Seems very tricky indeed to implement.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: The issue is that `0.0 == -0.0` **is** true, but that they’re not interchangeable in general (including as template arguments).

Comment: @Bathsheba: It’s meant to be just “use the bit pattern”, which isn’t too bad (but you the compiler developer do have to check for stray `==` being applied in your code).

Comment: What do you mean by “briefly explain [P0732R2] instead”?  (That paper’s model for template parameters has been completely replaced anyway.)

Comment: Davis: I was just wondering why it is on the compiler support list and why I completely failed to get the point in a quick scan of the paper. @NathanOliver : MSVC does surely not support it. I'm on 19.27. "Inconsistencies with NTTP" seems like an odd name for floating point support ;-)... but OK, if it's about the fringe cases...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It seems that the real question that can be answered here is about the **history** of this feature, so that whatever compiler support can be understood in context.

## Limitations on non-type template parameter types

People have been [wanting class-type non-type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4104147/8586227) for a long time.  The answers there are somewhat lacking; what really makes support for such template parameters (really, of non-trivial *user-defined* types) complicated is their unknown notion of **identity**: given

```
struct A {/*...*/};
template<A> struct X {};
constexpr A f() {/*...*/}
constexpr A g() {/*...*/}
X<f()> xf;
X<g()> &xg=xf;  // OK?
```

how do we decide whether `X<f()>` and `X<g()>` are the same type?  For integers, the answer seems intuitively obvious, but a class type might be something like `std::vector<int>`, in which case we might have

```
// C++23, if that
using A=std::vector<int>;
constexpr A f() {return {1,2,3};}
constexpr A g() {
  A ret={1,2,3};
  ret.reserve(1000);
  return ret;
}
```

and it's not clear what to make of the fact that both objects contain the same *values* (and hence compare equal with `==`) despite having very different **behavior** (*e.g.*, for iterator invalidation).

## [P0732](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf) Class types in non-type template parameters

It's true that this paper *first* added support for class-type non-type template parameters, in terms of the new `<=>` operator.  The logic was that classes that *defaulted* that operator were "transparent to comparisons" (the term used was "strong structural equality") and so programmers and compilers could agree on a definition of identity.

### [P1185](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1185r2.html) `<=> != ==`

Later it was realized that `==` should be separately defaultable for performance reasons (*e.g.*, it allows an early exit for comparing strings of different lengths), and the definition of strong structural equality was rewritten in terms of that operator (which comes for free along with a defaulted `<=>`).  This doesn't affect this story, but the trail is incomplete without it.

## [P1714](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1714r1.html) NTTP are incomplete without float, double, and long double!

It was discovered that class-type NTTPs and the unrelated feature of [constexpr `std::bit_cast`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0476r2.html) allowed a floating-point value to be smuggled into a template argument inside a type like `std::array<std::byte,sizeof(float)>`.  The semantics that would result from such a trick would be that every **representation** of a `float` would be a different template argument, despite the fact that `-0.0==0.0` and (given `float nan=std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();`) `nan!=nan`.  It was therefore proposed that floating-point values be allowed *directly* as template arguments, with those semantics, to avoid encouraging widespread adoption of such a hacky workaround.

At the time, there was a lot of confusion around the idea that (given `template<auto> int vt;`) `x==y` might differ from `&vt<x>==&vt<y>`), and the proposal was **rejected** as needing more analysis than could be afforded for C++20.

## [P1907R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r0.html) Inconsistencies with non-type template parameters

It turns out that `==` has a lot of problems in this area.  Even **enumerations** (which have always been allowed as template parameter types) can overload `==`, and using them as template arguments simply ignores that overload entirely.  (This is more or less necessary: such an operator might be defined in some translation units and not others, or might be defined differently, or have internal linkage, *etc*.)  Moreover, what an implementation needs to do with a template argument is **canonicalize** it: to *compare* one template argument (in, say, a call) to another (in, say, an explicit specialization) would require that the latter had somehow already been *identified* in terms of the former while somehow allowing the possibility that they might differ.

This notion of identity already differs from `==` for other types as well.  Even P0732 recognized that **references** (which can also be the type of template parameters) aren't compared with `==`, since of course `x==y` does not imply that `&x==&y`.  Less widely appreciated was that **pointers-to-members** also violate this correspondence: because of their different *behavior* in constant evaluation, pointers to different members of a union are distinct as template arguments despite comparing `==`, and pointers-to-members that have been cast to point into a base class have similar behavior (although their comparison is unspecified and hence disallowed as a direct component of constant evaluation).

In fact, in November 2019 GCC had already implemented basic support for class-type NTTPs *without* requiring any comparison operator.

### [P1837](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1837r0.html) Remove NTTPs of class type from C++20

These incongruities were so numerous that it had already been proposed that the entire feature be **postponed** until C++23.  In the face of so many problems in so popular a feature, a small group was commissioned to specify the significant changes necessary to save it.

### [P1907R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1907r1.html) (structural types)

These stories about template arguments of class type and of floating-point type reconverge in the revision of P1907R0 which retained its name but replaced its body with a *solution* to National Body comments that had *also* been filed on the same subject.  The (new) idea was to recognize that comparisons had never really been germane, and that the only consistent model for template argument identity was that two arguments were different if there was *any* means of distinguishing them during constant evaluation (which has the aforementioned power to distinguish pointers-to-members, *etc.*).  After all, if two template arguments produce the same specialization, that specialization must have *one* behavior, and it must be the same as would be obtained from using either of the arguments directly.

While it would be desirable to support a wide range of class types, the only ones that could be reliably supported by what was a new feature introduced (or rather rewritten) at almost the last possible moment for C++20 were those where every value that could be distinguished by the implementation could be distinguished by its clients—hence, only those that have all **public** members (that recursively have this property).  The restrictions on such *structural types* are not quite as strong as those on an aggregate, since any construction process is permissible so long as it is constexpr.  It also has plausible extensions for future language versions to support more class types, perhaps even `std::vector<T>`—again, by canonicalization (or serialization) rather than by comparison (which cannot support such extensions).

## The general solution

This newfound understanding has no relationship to anything else in C++20; class-type NTTPs using this model could have been part of **C++11** (which introduced constant expressions of class type).  Support was immediately extended to unions, but the logic is not limited to classes at all; it also established that the longstanding prohibitions of template arguments that were pointers to subobjects or that had floating-point type had also been motivated by confusion about `==` and were unnecessary.  (While this doesn't allow string literals to be template arguments for technical reasons, it *does* allow `const char*` template arguments that point to the first character of static character arrays.)

In other words, the forces that motivated P1714 were finally recognized as inevitable mathematical consequences of the fundamental behavior of templates and floating-point template arguments became part of C++20 after all.  However, neither floating-point nor class-type NTTPs were actually specified for C++20 by their original proposals, complicating "compiler support" documentation.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the very detailed answer. Learned a lot. Somehow, I did not notice it for 2 weeks. (sadly nobody else did, judging by the 0 upvotes) Just to make sure I got the conclusion correct: The C++20 standard allows/supports floating point as direct NTTPs as well as inside of (trivial) classes used as such!?

Comment: @non-user38741: Yes, they are allowed at either level (as are lvalue references).