# How are floats as non type template parameters treated when it comes to template specialization

Tags: c++, c++20, ieee-754, non-type-template-parameter

Consider [following program](https://godbolt.org/z/od5K87Y71):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<float f>
void fun(){
    std::cout << "val: " << f << "\n";
}

template<>
void fun<std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN()>(){
    std::cout << "sn\n";
}

int main() {
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN()!=std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN());
    fun<std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN()>();
    fun<std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()>();
}
```

It prints out:

> sn
> val: nan

So this makes me think that compiler does bitwise comparison of floats when it comes to template specialization consideration(see `static_assert`).
Is this correct?

I tried reading the 13.4.3 Template non-type arguments but it does not seem specified there, but I have really hard time reading the standard so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: It appears you're mostly correct [for floats it only cares if the representation is identical](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter) (scroll down to Template argument equivalence)

Comment: @Mgetz: [template_parameters#Template_argument_equivalence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_argument_equivalence) to not scroll manually :)

Comment: Notice that clang rejects the code. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qbx41GovK).

Comment: It’s not really a duplicate, since it’s about support for the feature, but [the history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63694879/8586227) does explain/motivate the rule.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think clang has not fully implemented the feature, I got unimplemented error when experimenting, can not reproduce it now.

Comment: @Jarod42  "or they are of floating-point type and their values are identical" now we get to discuss what did the poet mean when he said "identical"

Comment: standard ([temp#type-2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp#type-2)) doesn't give more info. Moreover, is *"values are the same"* (integral case) and *"values are identical"* (floating point) has same/identical meaning?

Comment: I prefer the consistent result from clang.

Comment: @DavisHerring your answer talks about floats in a way that does not fit my current example, maybe I misread it, but I understood that what you say is that different representations are counted as same, e.g 0.0 and -0.0  https://godbolt.org/z/cav3TeTTK

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: No, I said representations are *compared* instead of comparing values (with `==`).

Comment: @DavisHerring ok, then I misunderstood : "he semantics that would result from such a trick would be that every representation of a float would be a different template argument, despite the fact that -0.0==0.0 and (given float nan=std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();) nan!=nan. It was therefore proposed that floating-point values be allowed directly as template arguments, with those semantics, to avoid encouraging widespread adoption of such a hacky workaround."