# How to define default value for a ctor in template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I want to define default value for my templated container class in the template.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T, T TDefault>
class Thing
{
    T value;
    public:
    Thing(T p_value = TDefault):value(p_value) {}
    
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    // This works
    Thing<int, 42> thing;

    thing.print();

    // is there a way to make this work?
    Thing<std::string, std::string("Hello, World!")> thing2;

    thing2.print();
}
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious ... this should be possible, right?

http://cpp.sh/3gnwe

---

Basically I just want to make a container class that I can define the default value for when I define it. Instead of having to give a value for it every time I call the constructor.

---

Yeah I found a neat way around it, I won't post it here because it's not in line with the strict rules of questions and answers of this site.

Comment: Hm, it appears it's not possible. I need to do this differently 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4104147/why-cant-template-non-type-parameters-be-of-class-type/4105138

Comment: only interger including enum  and point  can use as  none type template parameter